# What is the meaning of the pink face?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

There is a pink face right beside the sparkle that indicates Shiny. What is the meaning of that face?

It's at the left side of the "marks" that you can put. You can see them in summary window or at the computer.

NOTES: Pokemon White (5th Generation).

I Have a Cabalion and a Zekrom with this pink face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means your pokemon had [Pokerus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9rus#In_Generation_V) but they're no longer contagious. They still have the EV growth boost though.

> The mechanics remain more or less the same, sharing similarity to the strain phenomenon in Generation II. However, a difference would be that the icon that would appear if a Pokémon has previously had Pokérus would be a pinkish color instead of the former yellow/orange color.

Comment: @MichelAyres the wiki article (which I linked) explains about all you need to know about pokerus in particulr